# the irbrc config file doesn't work for ruby 2 + rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, irb

The irbrc config file works on the rails 3.2 + ruby 1.9

Today I checked out a project, using rails 4 + ruby 2,

and I found it didn't load the `.irbrc` file (I put the file under my home directory)

When I ran into `irb` or `rails console`

What's the problem?

irbrc file

```
require 'irb/completion'                                                 
require 'hirb' ; Hirb.enable                                             

ARGV.concat ["--readline", "--prompt-mode", "simple"]                    
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 10000
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"                  

ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1 # Avoid log in Rails console      
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new STDOUT #顯示 SQL statements

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
    def drop_tbl (tblname)
        ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(eval(":"+tblname))
    end
    def show_tbls
        tbls = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
        tbls.each { |tbl|
            puts "#{tbl} #{tbl_name(tbl)}"
        }
    end
    def tbl_name(name)
        name.singularize.humanize.split().map{|x| x.capitalize}.join()
    end


    def cols (tblname)
        cols = eval("#{tblname}.column_names")
        ap(cols)
    end
```

Gemfile in the project

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'rails'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'thin'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the irb config file doesn’t get loaded in `rails console` if the file is erroneous. Run `ruby ~/.irbrc` to make sure that it evaluates without complaint. Additionally, you can verify that your console is even sourcing your irbrc by running `$LOAD_PATH.index{|s| s.include?('irbrc')}` within your console.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Pry. Try renaming the file to `.pryrc`.